# Python library that can generate scheduling diagram?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, scheduling

Can some one please suggest me any Python library/package that can generate scheduling diagrams? E.g boxes connected with arrows in a linear form?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not well suited for Stack Overflow, but anyway, I would at least suggest taking a look at http://www.pyqtgraph.org/ which has the capability to create flowcharts.